# How to make a textarea element look like normal text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create an html list where the user can edit the items as they appear on the page and navigate through them using standard keys and idioms from word processing applications. Something a little like http://www.workflowy.com

I've implemented this by giving each list item a textarea. Initially the style for the text editor hides it but if the list item class is set to "editor" then the textarea is shown and the list text is not. Example at http://jsfiddle.net/WWkWc/13/

If you go to that example you will notice that when you click on a list item it mostly looks like you expect it to (in this example you can only navigate by clicking on items, not with arrow keys). The only real problem with it is that the text box is taller than the line of text and so when the text box is showing the list item gets taller. I cannot figure out how to get rid of this effect.

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any chance you can use [contenteditable](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#contenteditable) instead?

http://jsfiddle.net/WWkWc/16/

```
<li contenteditable>
  <h2>Item text</h2>
</li>
```

More Examples:

http://html5demos.com/contenteditable

If you don't want to use content editable then the trick is to get the `h2` element and the `textarea` element to have the exact same properties. In this case I give them the same, font-size, font-family and height. I also set textarea to `block` because `h2` is a block level element. Finally I set overflow: hidden to prevent scroll arrows. I also simplified your javascript a bit.

http://jsfiddle.net/HM5V5/1/

```
h2, ul li textarea {
    font-size: 16px; 
    font-family: arial; 
    height: 19px;
}

ul li textarea {
    display: none;
    /*border: 1px solid gray;*/
    outline: 1;
    border: 0;
    resize:none;
    overflow: hidden;
}

ul li.editor textarea {
    display: block;
}
ul li.editor h2{
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: This looks pretty good, and I might end up using it but I would still like to know how to solve this issue with the textarea size, mostly to know how to solve it if the issue pops up in another scenario.

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't want to reinvent the wheel check out http://aloha-editor.org/ or http://jejacks0n.github.com/mercury/ which does just that. Both are HTML5 editors.